# How does a connected Julia set imply a member of the Mandelbrot Set?

Tags: julia-set, mandelbrot-set

I'm doing an introductory online course in complex analysis. In one of the lectures its stated that a complex number $c$ belongs to the Mandelbrot Set iff the Julia set $J(z^2 + c)$ is connected.

I also know that a complex number $c$ belongs to the Mandelbrot set iff performing the iteration $z_{n+1} = z^2_n + c, z_0=0$ results in a bounded set of values $z_n$ for all $n$.

Why are these two statements are equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

Julia set $J$ is compact, and the exterior component of its complement $D_\infty$ is completely invariant. This means that $f:D_\infty^*\to D_\infty^*$, where $D_\infty^*=D_\infty\cup\{\infty\}$ is a ramified covering. If the critical value $c$ does not belong to $D_\infty$, its orbit is bounded,  and the Riemann-Hurwitz applied to $f:D_\infty^*\to D_\infty^*$
says that $D_\infty^*$ is simply connected so its boundary $J=\partial D_\infty^*$ is connected. If $c\in D_\infty$, then by Riemann-Hurwitz $D_\infty$ is infinitely connected, therefore its boundary is disconnected.

Remark. I recommend that when taking this online course you keep an introductory book besides. The most elementary ones are books by Beardon and by Steinmetz, and the best one is the book by Milnor (freely available on Internet). There is also a book by Carleson and Gamelin, the most advanced one.